# Substituir aplicativo Android já publicado

Tags: google-play

Fala pessoal!

Estou começando a programar através do Android Studio, porém depois da última atualização o aplicativo que desenvolvi apresentou uma série de erros e tentando acertar estes erros acredito que tenha mais atrapalhado do que ajudado. Como já havia publicado este aplicativo na Play Store, gostaria de saber se tem como iniciar um novo projeto e substituir o aplicativo já publicado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, você pode fazer isso mas ter dois requisitos:

- Tem que ser o mesmo package do projeto anterior, o package é usado como identificador do seu aplicativo, então se ele mudar o google play vai entender que é um app diferente.
- Tem que usar o mesmo certificado para assinar o app, ou seja quando você gerar o build do projeto você tem  que usar o mesmo certificado que usou antes. Guarde com cuidado o certificado pois se você perder ele não vai ser possivel enviar atualizações do app para a loja.

Tenha em mente que para você vai ser um app diferente mas se seguir essas regras para a google play vai ser so uma atualização do app

Comment: Muito obrigado!